# dayjs().utcOffset(0).startOf('date').toDate() returns yesterdays date, not todays

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, dayjs

I'm using dayjs to get a date at midnight, for a passed date string (**DD/MM/YYYY**).

What I'm currently trying is like this:

```
const myDate = '31/08/2023';
const midnight = dayjs(myDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY').utcOffSet(0).startOf('date').toDate()
console.log(midnight) // 2023-08-30T00:00:00.000Z
```

As you can see, the value of `midnight` is logging as 30th August, which I'm assuming is to do with time zones (I'm UK based)

The dayjs object for the date looks like this:

```
{
  '$L': 'en',
  '$u': undefined,
  '$d': 2023-08-30T23:00:00.000Z,
  '$x': {},
  '$y': 2023,
  '$M': 7,
  '$D': 31,
  '$W': 4,
  '$H': 0,
  '$m': 0,
  '$s': 0,
  '$ms': 0
}
```

What can I do to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: You're currently on Summer Time, right? An hour ahead?

Comment: When you make the date object, it uses *your* time zone. Then you set it to UTC, which is an hour behind you. If you don't want that, then don't set the offset to 0.

Comment: A date–only timestamp should be parsed as local midnight at the start of the day (i.e. 00:00:00). What is the purpose of the other methods?

Comment: Thanks @Pointy & RobG - you're right, offsetting the utc was causing the issues. Long day - appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the issue you're facing is related to time zone offsets and how Day.js handles them. The unexpected date output of August 30th instead of August 31st is due to a combination of your local time zone and the use of .utcOffset(0).

To address this issue and get the correct result, you can use the following approach:

```
const dayjs = require('dayjs');
const utc = require('dayjs/plugin/utc'); // Import the utc plugin
dayjs.extend(utc); // Extend dayjs with the utc plugin

const myDate = '31/08/2023';
const midnight = dayjs.utc(myDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY').startOf('day').toDate(); // Use utc() and startOf('day')
console.log(midnight); // Output: 2023-08-31T00:00:00.000Z
```

Please note that the output will be in UTC time. If you want to display it in your local time zone, you can use the .local() method:

```
const localMidnight = dayjs(midnight).local().toDate();
console.log(localMidnight); // Output will be adjusted to your local time zone
```